# 72-gon with points (cos(k35°), sin(k35°))

Tags: polygons

[image]

This is the question I am given, and I have a model answer for it as well... but I am having difficulty understanding it.

What I can see is that the points are on a unit circle. Of course I can also see that $360°$$/$$72$ $=$ $5°$.

Other than that I don't know how to approach this question.

Answer (score 0):

As the points are on the unit circle, all you have to show is the polar angles of the $72$ vertices are attained.

In particular, you should have $k\cdot 35\equiv 5\mod 360\,$ for some $k\in\mathbf Z$. This is equivalent to:
$$7k\equiv 1\mod72$$
So you have to find the inverse of $7$ modulo $72$. This is done through the *Extended Euclidean Algorithm*. You'll get 
$$k\equiv 31\mod 72$$
From ther, it is not difficult to obtain the polar angles of the other vertices.